# Conservative Force and $1/r^2$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work

Does the inverse square law have anything to do with conservative behavior of the central forces?

Answer (score 10):

Not really, no. A field is conservative if it can be written as the gradient of a potential function:

$$\mathbf{F}=\nabla f$$

You could equally well define the potentials $f=kr^2$, or $f=kr^5$, etc., which will produce vector fields that are respectively linear and quartic with $r$.

Answer (score 2):

All central forces (where central means spherically symmetric, that is independent of angular variables) are conservative: see the quesiton [Are all central forces conservative? Wikipedia must be wrong](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38874/are-all-central-forces-conservative-wikipedia-must-be-wrong).